# ORACLE SQL: How to update specific dates in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update the expiration date of some articles on a website. I listed the articles with:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTENT WHERE dat_publishto = '20-JAN.  -01';
```

How can I update these records to a later date?

Comment: Sample data would help a lot. What is the datatype of `dat_publishto`? If it's a date, the Oracle syntax is [like this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't store dates as strings, and that your date format doesn't look that awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE CONTENT 
SET dat_publishto  = '19-DEC-14'
WHERE dat_publishto = '20-JAN-01';
```

Comment: I tried out on a different date and I got:

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE CONTENT 
SET '11-FEBR. -28' = '19-DEC.  -14'
WHERE dat_publishto = '11-FEBR. -28'
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 5

Comment: You should learn, how to use update query in oracle. You should mention the column on left side not values. Please check my updates answer\

Comment: @vutren: why didn't you run the statement as shown in the question? You might need to change the date _format_ depending on your NLS settings though (that's why I prefer ANSI dates like: `date '2019-12-14` that is unambiguous and works with every NLS configuration

Comment: @VigneshKumarA if `dat_publishto` is a `date` column, you should use [the Oracle syntax for date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1), not a text string.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports a clean syntax for inputting date constants.  I would recommend using it:

```
UPDATE CONTENT 
    SET dat_publishto  = DATE '2014-12-19'
    WHERE dat_publishto = DATE '2001-01-20';
```

Your format is quite awkward.  Although you could use `TO_DATE()`, I would recommend simply using a more standard literal value.